# Nth-child Targeting Every Other Child But Always Including The Last

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out a CSS nth-child formula to target every other child, but always including the last child.

For example:

- With 1 child, it will target the single child.
- With 2 children it will target the 2nd child.
- With 3 children it will target children 1 and 3.
- With 4 children it will target children 2 and 4.
- With 5 children it will target children 1 3 and 5.

And so on...

Is this possible with only CSS? I'm okay with using something other than or in addition to nth-child but trying to stay CSS only.

Comment: @Paulie_D I did Google and search Stack Overflow for my exact question title. I've also tried some formulas that didn't work. I could post them here, but I don't remember each one I've tried to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this fine for you?

```css
li:nth-last-child(2n+1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: After reading more about nth-last-child this will be useful in the future too. Thanks again.